# How to count values in a single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
    | ID | X1 | X2 | X3 | .. | Xn |
    +----+----+----+----+----+----+
    | 1  | x  | '' | x  | '' | '' |
    +----+----+----+----+----+----+
    | 2  | '' | '' | x  | '' | '' |
    +----+----+----+----+----+----+
    | 3  | x  | x  | x  | '' | x  |
    +----+----+----+----+----+----+
'' = Empty string, not null
```

Now I want to know how many 'x' are in row 2 or 3 or n. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Using MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: What RDBMS is this for (and version?)

Comment: Is this homework? It sure looks like homework. Please tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I am 31 years old, I am not doing homework anymore. ;) Just trying to get used to SQL and practicing on some self-given exercises. Actually I am trying to create a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game and wanted to count the X in a row (so actually Xn where n > 3 could never happen, but I hoped for a solution without a select over every single column). -- Added database to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ID,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   (VALUES (X1),
                       (X2),
                       (X3),
                       /* ... */
                       (Xn)) T(X)
        WHERE  X = 'X') AS Num
FROM   YourTable
```

Comment: If I wouldn't want to write every single column, would dynamic SQL be the best solution? I just would create a while-loop and add all x-columns to the SQL string. Or maybe there is a better way?

Comment: @Feroc - You could use dynamic SQL to generate a query including all columns or you could also consider restructuring so that you store each value in its own row in a table with columns `ID, Index, Value`

Comment: You have to write every column; there's no choice if you're doing it in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store the data this way. Instead, store it in a table of XCoord, YCoord, Value. Then you can do something like:

```
SELECT     XCoord, COUNT(Value) AS XTotal
FROM         TicTacTable
WHERE     (Value = 'x')
GROUP BY XCoord
```

Comment: I would do that, if the playing field would be outside the sql-database, but in this case the game is played directly on the database.